# How come i can use es6 import for libraries which produce commonJS and UMD bundles only?

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules, rollupjs, umd

I was wondering

I am used to work with Webpack and bundle my own libraries to UMD and ESM.

But now I see that some of the libraries I am using, do not even create ESM bundles.
Even though, I am able to `import` them using es6 syntax!.

If it is the case, does it mean that modern bundlers like webpack and rollup knows how to `import` the modules without them having to be defined in `ESM` format?
Is it really necessary that I produce ESM format for my own builds?

Comment: Fairly old bundlers like webpack and transpilers like typescript started supporting import syntax before the specification of the import syntax was written. They implemented them with an assumption that the ECMAscript comittee would create a spec that would be compatible with node.js. This turned out to be a false assumption. Node.js had to separate the implementations of commonjs and esm style modules because it is impossible to unify them. But older transpilers still pretend like they can be unified

Comment: To be clear, bundlers like webpack implement non-standards compliant import syntax. Node decided to be standards compliant thus could not merge the behavior of esm and commonjs modules